How to access the webapp on browser from aws ecs?
I used AWS ECS to deploy a webapp.
I pulled the image from dockerhub
The webapp was EXPOSED on port 8080
Then I set up the cluster, task definition and service to run 3 tasks. I used an application load balance to distribute traffic.
But when I use the DNS of the load balancer or the public IP of the task on web browser, I was unable to access the App.
I confirm the port are allowed for traffic in the security group. In fact the SG is set to allow all traffic.
The VPC, route table, subnet, IGW are default.

make sure your target group is using port 8080

Does the target group say the ECS targets are healthy?
